# Limiting users download speed - Amazon s3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an AWS account and I'm currently using an S3 bucket to store music files in, however I would like to restrict the download speeds to certain users on my site (Premium Users, Non Premium) I know this is possible to do as a lot of websites do this, although I'm not sure it is possible with Amazon S3 though.

- Even if it is not possible to limit download speed, would it be possible to limit the download size per users? (e.g. Premium users can download 1GB a day, no premium 50mb a day)?

My website is hosted on an Apache webserver and uses PHP&MySQL. The S3 bucket is just used to store the music.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't throttle the download speed from S3 unless you proxy the connection, but that wouldn't make much sense.  Besides, throttling would be a completely manufactured limitation and wouldn't make sense with S3 because you're charged per gigabyte, not on your throughput.

Yes, you can limit download size.  This would have to be done from your application though.